# GroupBy so that a List<T> becomes a List<List<T>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
List<Something> somethings = new List<Something>()
{
    new Something(){ Connection = "Bob" },
    new Something(){ Connection = "Bob" },
    new Something(){ Connection = "Peter" },
}
```

I would like to end up with the following:

```
List<List<<Something>> groupedSomethings = new List<List<<Something>>()
    new List<Something>()
    {
        new Something(){ Connection = "Bob" },
        new Something(){ Connection = "Bob" }
    }
    new List<Something>()
    {
        new Something(){ Connection = "Peter" },
    }
}
```

I can't get the Linq statement right.

I imagine it to look something like this:

```
List<List<<Something>> groupedSomethings = somethings
    .GroupBy(x => x.Connection)
    .SelectMany(somethings => new List<Something>());
```

How would you approach this?

Comment: Show the LINQ statement(s) you have tried so we know what you're thinking.

Comment: Any reason why it has been down voted twice and a close requested?

Comment: List<List< Something>> groupedSomethings = somethings.GroupBy(s => s.Connection).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();

Comment: I guess those users think you should show your effort.

Comment: @fdafadf That is my answer already. Please post an answer, but not comments-as-an-answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Well, those users should be slower to judge. :) - Thanks for the answer Patrick.

Comment: var results = somethings.GroupBy(x => x.Connection).Select(x => x.Select(y => new Something() { Connection = y.Connection }).ToList()).ToList();

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 -- Maybe so, but have you seen how this place works?

Comment: @rory.ap - Pahahah. indeed :) Your comment was good, it was like... telling me how to improve it. Other people just vote and don't say anything. <roars>

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 -- For the record, I didn't DV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`, and then get the values from the group:

```
var lists = somethings.GroupBy(x => x.Connection).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: AHHHH Select instead of SelectMany and not declaring new list was the key. Thanks mate!